# Implicit conversion of generic type T to JsValue in Play! Framework

Tags: json, scala, generics, playframework

I have a problem with declaring of generic method in Play 2.6 application that converts JSON to instance of one of the case class models.

All models declared with helper objects and formatters:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{Json, OFormat}
case class Shot(id: Long, likes_count: Long)
object Shot {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Shot] = Json.format[Shot]
}

val s1: Shot = Json.toJson(f).as[Shot] // Works great

def testJsonGeneric[T](js: JsValue)(implicit ev: OFormat[T]): T = {
    js.as[T](ev)
}

val s2: Shot = testJsonGeneric(Json.toJson(f)) // could not find implicit value for parameter ev: play.api.libs.json.OFormat[T]. Compilation failed
```

The last line of code throws

> could not find implicit value for parameter ev: play.api.libs.json.OFormat[T]

But if I call my generic method like this (with explicit formatter) it works just fine:

```
val s2: Shot = testJsonGeneric(Json.toJson(f))(Shot.format)
```

However, it looks like if I expect my JSON to return a list of objects I have to define an extra formatter for List[Shot] to pass explicitly to the method when default Play's json.as[List[Shot]] could easily allow me to do this with a single existing formatter like the one that already defined in the helper object.

So, is it even possible to provide formatters implicitly for generic type T in my case?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do this, you just have to change the declaration a bit.

Move the case class and companion declaration outside the method, and then explicitly `import Shot._` to bring the implicit in scope:

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json, OFormat}

object Foo {
  case class Shot(id: Long, likes_count: Long)
  object Shot {
    implicit def format: OFormat[Shot] = Json.format[Shot]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import Shot._

    val f = Shot(1, 2)

    def testJsonGeneric[T](js: JsValue)(implicit ev: OFormat[T]): T = {
      js.as[T](ev)
    }

    val s2: Shot = testJsonGeneric(Json.toJson(f))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to do the same trick if I would like to return a list of Shots from my generic method and I want it to be properly deserialized without implementing of an extra OFormat[List[Shot]]:

import Shots._; /* marked as unused */ val shots : List[Shot] = testJsonGeneric(Json.toJson(List(f1, f2)))

Comment: @AlexeySirenko Implicit resolution is recursive, if there is a format for list, it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, looks like method expects Format[List[T]] and ignores imports of helper objects